# RabbitMQ for http/https request queuing in Django

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq

One of my clients wants to use RabbitMQ for request queuing on his Django DRF powered web app. the app is simple just saving and listing information with attachments (over S3 storage) with high traffic. 
As I know RabbitMQ acts as message broker which can be helpful while doing long tasks/sending emails/ generating PDFs. 
I am curious to know that in my scenario can I use rabbitMQ? and if yes then what will be the advantages of using it.